# Mechanisms for stack buffer overflow detection?

Tags: security, gcc, stack, overflow

Compiling and running the following:

```
 void main() {
  int array[10];
  array[10] = 2;
}
```

Which is to my understanding stack overrun.

GCC does not seem to detect the problem.

Only when I compile using the additional flag `-fstack-protector-all` I get the stack trace.

Is there a way to detect erroneous illegal memory access for a binary compiled and linked without the gcc flag `-fstack-protector-all`, or it will run normally and the process would then access memory which does not belong to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, many modern distros will enable `-fstack-protector` and other security measures (`_FORTIFY_SOURCE`, `-fPIE`, etc.) by default so you program will get some protection even without you asking for it.

Secondly, if that's not the case and buffer overflow results in a *really bad error* (e.g. accessing invalid memory or overwriting return address), kernel will kill the application and dump core.

More subtle errors (which cause program to malfunction but not in obvious ways), will go undetected though. There's no way to diagnose them without e.g. recompiling with ASan.

P.S. Keep in mind that simple one-line buffer overflows like the one in your question tend to be optimized out by compiler. My GCC 5.4.0 simply dropped access to `array[10]`.

Comment: it tends to be optimized out, but in case it is used (I made small possible testcase) I could also add a print to the value contained in the array, so it wont be considered as dead code

Comment: @Bionix1441 Even when it's used, GCC may notice that you read past end of the array and replace memory read with 0 (it's UB anyway, so compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants). [Here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/test/asan/TestCases/stack-buffer-overflow.cc#L10) is one example how one can fool compiler to prevent it from such unwanted optimizations.